# JMeter Query - Different User use different file locations for same HTTP Request

Tags: jmeter

Suppose a total of 50 users and one HTTP request/sampler were created so in that case we provide one input file when run  Api then all 50 users use the same input files (same input file location )and some requests failed.
We want to make ideas or scripts for users to use different file locations so not chance to fail request or file not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the file name/location just like any other request parameter, username, etc.

The configuration element which is most frequently user for parameterization is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

However if you don't want to manually manage the file content and protect yourself from "file not founds" it makes sense to consider going for [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin which reads the files in the given folder and stores them into a JMeter Variable so each thread/iteration will pick the next file from the pool.

You can install Directory Listing Config plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)